# Reg exp to replace variables in URI

Tags: regex, expression

I'm completely rubbish at regular expressions so need a bit of help please! I have a URI that looks like:

/collections/stationery/colour-green+size-large

and I want to replace the colour-green (and in this case the +) with nothing. The colour is not necessarily green so could be colour-blue or colour-red etc. It could also appear anywhere at the end of the URI e.g.

/collections/stationery/size-large+colour-green

so it might not always be followed by a + sign.

Never mind the code to achieve this I'm just after the regular expression, i.e., one I can whack in here: http://regexlib.com/RETester.aspx and it'll match the correct patterns.

Many thanks

Comment: can you have more than 2 elements (colour & size) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will match "colour-green" in both of your URI's along with the following `+` in the first URI. It would also match if it was a different color.

```
colour-\w+\+?
```

If you wanted to make sure and allow hex color codes, you could do something like this:

```
colour-[^+]+\+?
```

Replacing the above with nothing on your URI's will result in what I believe is your desired results:

`.../colour-green+size-large` - `.../size-large`
`.../size-large+colour-green` - `.../size-large+`
...if you have more than just 2 variables:
`.../shape-square+colour-green+size-large` - `.../shape-square+size-large`

Also, if you want the second (`.../size-large+colour-green`) to remove the "+" before the match without affecting the "+" before the match in the 3rd example. You could use a negative lookahead like this:

```
(?:\+(?!.*\+))?colour-[^+]+\+?
```

Comment: Wow thanks - wish I understood regular expressions a bit more!